# define-match-expander

Tags: macros, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

about the define-match-expansion, there are rare materials and example codes to illustrate the concepts. I am having a hard time to "decode" what the documentation says:

```
(define-match-expander id proc-expr)
(define-match-expander id proc-expr proc-expr)
```

> Binds id to a match expander.
>
> The first proc-expr subexpression must
>   evaluate to a transformer that
>   produces a pat for match. Whenever id
>   appears as the beginning of a pattern,
>   this transformer is given, at
>   expansion time, a syntax object
>   corresponding to the entire pattern
>   (including id). The pattern is the
>   replaced with the result of the
>   transformer.
>
> A transformer produced by a second
>   proc-expr subexpression is used when
>   id is used in an expression context.
>   Using the second proc-expr, id can be
>   given meaning both inside and outside
>   patterns.

Can anyone give some example codes to illustrate the two usages of the define-match-expander here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind match-expander is that you can extend the 'match' form to handle new pattern forms of your own design.

So, here's a (somewhat pointless) example that defines an "aba" match form that matches patterns of one thing followed by another thing followed by the first thing again (hence, "aba"):

```
#lang racket

(define-match-expander aba
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ a b) #'(list a b a)])))

(match '(3 4 3)
  [(aba x y) (printf "x = ~a, y = ~a" x y)])
```

The second form allows you to add a separate expansion to be used outside of match patterns, like this:

```
#lang racket

(define-match-expander aba
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ a b) #'(list a b a)]))
  (lambda (stx)
    #'(error "please don't use aba outside of patterns.")))

(match '(3 4 3)
  [(aba x y) (printf "x = ~a, y = ~a\n" x y)])

(aba x y)
```

Caveat: whuffo the extra pair of parens around the pattern? Not sure, sorry.

Comment: so your example shows that 
1. whether '(3 4 3) matches the form as aba, the new pattern.
2. can you explain how syntax-case works?
I don't see anywhere that can check a b a form. Or say: I guess x is bind to 3, y is bind to 4, but where shows '(3 4 3) satisfied the a b a pattern?

Comment: or my other understanding is that: the define-match-expander, defines a new pattern form to be used in match. The syntax-case, #'(list a b a) is in tail position, which will be the return expression, which is used to match '(3 4 3)? if it matches, the x will be bind to 3, and y to 4? Are these the things going on for the example code?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a plausible summary. Apologies for my use of syntax-case rather than the simpler syntax-rules; I'm just used to using syntax-case.

Comment: Well, glad to see *Yes* anyway. Your example helps!  (I am just feeling I am not quite following the documentations, I would prefer examples)

Answer (score 2):

This is a really old question, but I'd like to add the example using "syntax-rules" for the same "aba" pattern:

```
(define-match-expander aba
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(aba a b) (list a b a)]))

(match '(3 4 3)
  [(aba x y) (printf "x = ~a, y = ~a" x y)])
```

Left-hand side `(aba a b)` is the thing going in the `match`, the right-hand side `(list a b a)` is the substitution.

```
(match '(3 4 3)
  [(aba x y) (printf "x = ~a, y = ~a" x y)])
```

is replaced by

```
(match '(3 4 3)
  [(list x y x) (printf "x = ~a, y = ~a" x y)])
```

The nice part is that the new matcher works for ALL "match-whatever" functions, like:

```
(match-define (aba x y) (list 1 2 1))
(printf "x = ~a, y = ~a" x y
```